# Retrieve Data From ManyToMany Field in Form Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to retrieve data from a modelform in which the user can select multiple options for a group permissions; for this, I am using a ManyToMany relationship.

The form is structured like this:

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Gruppo
        fields = ("nome", "Autorizzazioni")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["Autorizzazioni"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["Autorizzazioni"].queryset = Permesso.objects.all()
        self.fields["Autorizzazioni"].required = False
```

The field called Autorizzazioni has a ManyToMany relation with a Permesso model. The problem is that, since I wrote the form out manually (boss'choice), the queryset retrieved by the form is empty(althoug the ids are set correctly)

This means that any choice that the user made is not saved, and the ones that were already selected aren't any longer. I use a simple form.save() which, according to documentation, should also save m2m relationships.

Can you guys help me?

EDIT:

this is the view:

```
def gruppo_detail(request, id=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated or not can_view(request):
        return redirect("/")
    instance = get_object_or_404(Gruppo, id=id)
    permessi = Permesso.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GroupForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            action.send(request.user, verb="ha modificato il gruppo", target=instance, ip=get_ip(request))
            return redirect("/gruppi/")
   else:
       form = GroupForm(instance=instance)
```

and this is the template:

```
<form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right" method="POST" action="{{request.path}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <!-- begin:: Portlet Body-->
                        <div class="m-portlet__body">
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                {{form.nome.errors}}
                                <label for="id_nome" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label"><span class="m--font-danger" aria-required="true">* </span> Nome</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control m-input" name="nome" value="{{gruppo.nome}}" id="id_nome" required>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                    <label for="id_Autorizzazioni" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Autorizzazioni</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                        <div class="m-checkbox-list">
                                            {% for permesso in permessi %}
                                            <label class="m-checkbox">
                                                {% is_present permesso gruppo.Autorizzazioni.all as checked %}
                                                 <input type="checkbox" id="id_Autorizzazioni_{{permesso.id}}" value="{{permesso.id}}" {% if checked %}  checked {% endif %}>{{permesso.nome}}
                                                <span></span>
                                            </label>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                        </div>
                        {% include '_bottom_add.html' %}
                    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to show the template and the view.

Comment: sorry, i'll add it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given your checkboxes a `name` attribute, so the browser will never send any data. It should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Autorizzazioni" id="id_Autorizzazioni_{{permesso.id}}" value="{{permesso.id}}" {% if checked %}  checked {% endif %}>{{permesso.nome}}
```